# What do i enter as for the "redirect Url" when creating a Facebook service?

Tags: c#, facebook, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to implement the **Xamarin.Social** component into my app. That requires a parameter named **RedirectUrl** that i can't find anywhere in the Facebook developers console, and google hardly returns results.

```
public static FacebookService Facebook
{
    get
    {
        if (mFacebook == null)
        {
            mFacebook = new FacebookService() {
                ClientId = "App ID here, that works fine",
                RedirectUrl = new Uri (" ??? ")
            };
        }

        return mFacebook;
    }
}
```

Where can i find that parameter? I have tried various things so far but non of them seemed to work so i think its not worth posting here. I really need this for a project to get done. Thanks, i appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this parameter on your application settings on facebook developer.
If you are developing a desktop or mobile app, you can use this url https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html as your redirect_url